# Modern way to use SIMD instructions in C++ using g++

Tags: c++, gcc, simd

I'm building a ray tracer and in many cases I need to make additions and multiplications on three floats.

In such cases I've been doing it the naive way:

```
class Color{
    float mR, mG, mB;

    ...
    Color operator+(const Color &color) const
    {
        return Color(mR + color.mR,
                     mG + color.mG,
                     mB + color.mB);
    }

    Color operator*(const Color &color) const
    {
        return Color(mR * color.mR / COLOR_MAX,
                     mG * color.mG / COLOR_MAX,
                     mB * color.mB / COLOR_MAX);
    }
}
```

This would also happen in equivalent classes such as `Point` or `Vect3`.

Then I heard about SIMD instructions and they look like a good fit for what I'm doing. So, of course, I googled it and found this piece of code:

```
typedef int v4sf __attribute__((mode(V4SF))); // Vector of three single floats

union f4vector
{
    v4sf v;
    float f[4];
};
```

Which first of all uses an extra four I don't need right now. But then gcc warns me that:

> specifying vector types with `__attribute__ ((mode))` is deprecated

I'd like to know how to do this in C++14 (if it even makes a difference at all) and I can't seem to find any other way of doing it.

Comment: There's about 7,000 gallons if you look from line 600 onwards in here... https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/filter.cpp

Comment: The "modern" way is to get a compiler that can automatically vectorize your code for you. :-) Anyway, I'm pretty sure that the rest of that message says "use the 'vector_size' attribute instead", but maybe that's just on Clang?

Comment: ISO C++14 doesn't have this feature; it's a GNU extension.  The compiler option for C++14 with GNU extensions is `-std=gnu++14`.  But then like Cody mentioned, you use `__attribute__((vector_size(16)))` for a 16-byte vector of whatever type you apply it to.  It's [right there in the manual under gcc vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).

Comment: Manual vectorization is also often done using Intel's intrinsics, with `__m128i` and/or `__m128` or `__m128d` data types.  See the [SSE](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info) tag wiki for a few good links.  GNU C vector extensions are platform-neutral, but they are kind of "their own thing" and don't make it as easy to use exactly the functionality of the SIMD instruction set you're targetting.

Comment: Assuming you understand SoA versus AoS? With a union that is a a single dimension then each element can be thought of as the same as the structure if both parts are the same length... Otherwise you need a SoA or do some gathering of the data before the SIMD.

Comment: If someone is seeing this now, it may be worth checking out http://quantstack.net/xsimd